# Javascript - restructure array of objects according to common value

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

My input array of objects it is like this, I have an input array that looks like this :

```
[{"id": 657, "name": "Amadeus Basin", "contenttype": "province"}
{"id": 1173, "name": "Amazonas Basin", "contenttype": "province"}
{"id": 373, "name": "American Samoa", "contenttype": "countries"}
{"id": 1, "name": "Samoa", "contenttype": "marine"}
{"id": 796, "name": "Amhara", "contenttype": "province"}]
```

What I would like to achieve it would be:

```
[
    {
    "contenttype": "province",
    "content" : [
        {
            "id": 657,
            "name": "Amadeus Basin"
        },
        {
            "id": 1173,
            "name": "Amazonas Basin"
        },
        {
            "id": 796,
            "name": "Amhara"
        }
    ]
    }, {

        "contenttype": "countries",
        "content": [
            {
                "id": 373,
                "name" : "American Samoa"
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        "contenttype": "countries",
        "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name" : "Samoa"
        }
    ]

    }

]
```

splitting objects in the array according to one value and creating sub-arrays of the same objects inside these newly created objects.
It would be good also using lodash.

Comment: it would be good, if you add an attempt.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: `_.groupBy(data, 'contenttype')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function to iterate over each item and then check it existence in the array, if not found add new one, if found - push into it

```js
const data = [{"id": 657, "name": "Amadeus Basin", "contenttype": "province"},
{"id": 1173, "name": "Amazonas Basin", "contenttype": "province"},
{"id": 373, "name": "American Samoa", "contenttype": "countries"},
{"id": 1, "name": "Samoa", "contenttype": "marine"},
{"id": 796, "name": "Amhara", "contenttype": "province"}];

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, item) => {

  const found = acc.find(i => i.contenttype === item.contenttype);
  const content = {id: item.id, name: item.name};
  
  if(found) {
     found.content.push(content);
  } else {
     acc.push({contenttype: item.contenttype, content: [content] })
  }
  
  return acc;

}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: why downvote? agree question is not well defined.... but.... result seems exactly what OP is expecting IMHO.....

Answer (score 1):

You could use `_.groupBy` and map the wanted properties.

```js
var data = [{ id: 657, name: "Amadeus Basin", contenttype: "province" }, { id: 1173, name: "Amazonas Basin", contenttype: "province" }, { id: 373, name: "American Samoa", contenttype: "countries" }, { id: 1, name: "Samoa", contenttype: "marine" }, { id: 796, name: "Amhara", contenttype: "province" }],
    result = _(data)
        .groupBy('contenttype')
        .map((value, key) => ({
            contenttype: key,
            content: _.map(value, v => _.pick(v, ['id', 'name']))
        }))
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```